# How can I write an if statement in resources.Get Hugo?

Tags: go, hugo

I have the following code:

```
{{ with resources.Get .Site.Params.image }}
    <meta property="og:image" content="{{ .Permalink }}" />
{{ end }}
```

I get a image path in the `config.toml` file. However I now want to be able to overwrite the file by frontmatter data... Something like this (in pseudo code):

```
{{ if isset .Image }}
{{ $image := .Image }}
{{ else }}
{{ $image := .Site.Params.image }}
{{ end }}
{{ with resources.Get $image }}
...
```

How can I write this statement? Also if you have good tutorials on these statements and syntax let me know!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `or` function:

```
{{ with resources.Get (or .Params.thumbnailImage .Site.Params.ogImage) }}
    <meta property="og:image" content="{{ .Permalink }}" />
{{ end }}
```

Comment: I like it. Very clean and concise, I would have used a with else statement. This is better I think.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I updated to @brendan solution.

---

This is my solution:

```
{{ $ogImage := "" }}
{{ if .Params.thumbnailImage }}
    {{ $ogImage = .Params.thumbnailImage }}
{{ else }}
    {{ $ogImage = .Site.Params.ogImage }}
{{ end }}
{{ $ogImageRender := resources.Get $ogImage }}
{{ with $ogImageRender }}
    <meta property="og:image" content="{{ .Permalink }}" />
{{ end }}
```

- `:=` defines variables and set initial value
- `=` set variables to another value

Comment: Brendan's is better. go for his, concise, readable and does exactly what you want.

Comment: @Rogelio 100% agreed ;)